# In the tube or on the tube?

Tags: prepositions

If I would like to ask, if someone reads the news on / in the tube?

(btw Tube being the underground in London)

Which one is correct?

Thanks,

Comment: If you are referring to London's underground railway system then, 'in the tube' means in the station and 'on the tube' means inside the train. At least that's what it means to me and I used to live in London.

Comment: I'd say "in the tube" meant "in the London Underground system as a whole". E.g. "you meet a lot of nutters in the tube".   I agree that "on the tube" means actually on the train. The distinction isn't absolute. I'm another ex-Londoner.

Comment: Adding to the confusion, "on the tube" could mean "on the television," which is a plausible place to get news.

Comment: @Lostinfrance - It's a fine point. By 'in the station' I'm including the surrounding walkways and so on. I think we agree basically.

Comment: I no longer watch the news on the tube -- use the web instead.  And I've never tried to watch the news from inside the tube -- not sure how you'd even get in there.

Comment: @chasly from UK, yes, I think we broadly agree. However a quick look at the Oracle of Google suggests that this distinction is only a tendency, with many exceptions in each direction. Hence I am not sure enough of it to make my comment into a proper answer. I'll yield to others with more confidence or knowledge.

Comment: @user867 - Not many TVs have cathode-ray tubes these days. They're all flat screens!

Comment: @Lostinfrance - What search terms did you use?

Comment: @HotLicks- you’d need to ask Mike TV about Wonka vision.